# How can we pass current date-time to a angularjs function in a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to get present date and pass it to the function - **same-or-earlier-than** But in the run-time, it does not pass date value to this class.  Below is my html code. I am trying to get date from javascript and printing it for test. 
the date is printed, but when passing it to the function, it doesnt work.

```
  <div class="row">
 <div class="hh-dock-page-view panel">
 <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="hh-page-header">Issue Detail</h2>
    <h3 class="hh-action-heading"><span ng-hide="ctrl.readOnly">Edit </span>Details - {{ctrl.returnCurDate()}} - {{ctrl.issue.issue_date}}"</h3>
    <hh-model-form name="issueForm" model="ctrl.issue" page-controller="ctrl" submit-success="ctrl.submitSuccess" hide-actions="ctrl.readOnly">
        <h2 class="hh-page-header extra-margin">{{modelFormCtrl.model.provider_name_spec_prac}} - {{ctrl.issue.issue_date}}</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">

          <hh-field-messages>
            <label for="issue_date">Issue Date</label>
            <hh-american-date-field
               id="issue_date"
               name="issue_date"
               ng-model="modelFormCtrl.model.issue_date"
               ng-blur="modelFormCtrl.pageController.setStatus(this)"
               ng-disabled="modelFormCtrl.pageController.readOnly"
               same-or-earlier-than="{{ctrl.issue.issue_date}}"
               same-or-earlier-than-msg="Enter a date that is on or before Resolution Date."
               >
            </hh-american-date-field>
        </hh-field-messages>
            <div class="hh-breath"></div>
          </div>
          </div>



    </hh-model-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here below is my angularjs file:

```
angular.module('Prm')
.controller('IssueDetailController',
['$scope', '$q', '$route', '$location', '$routeParams', 'moment', 'IssueService', 'IssuePriorityService', 'ActivityService',
 'ProviderService', 'DirtyFormCheckingService', 'ConfirmBox', 'ErrorAlertService', 'AlertBoxService', 'DateService',
 'ReferenceTableDataAdapter',
function ($scope, $q, $route, $location, $routeParams, moment, IssueService, IssuePriorityService, ActivityService, ProviderService,
          DirtyFormCheckingService, ConfirmBox, ErrorAlertService, AlertBoxService, DateService,
          ReferenceTableDataAdapter){
    'use strict';
    var ctrl = this,
        isExisting = false,
        issuePriority = null,
        initPromises = [];

    var currentUser = cpm.authentication.user.report_ownership_role_code;
    ctrl.isAdmin = cpm.authentication.user.dss_role_list.split(",").includes('USERADMIN');
    ctrl.readOnly = true;

    var getNameForEdit = function(row) {
        if (ctrl.readOnly) return 'View';
        return 'Edit';
    };

    ctrl.providerAdapter = ReferenceTableDataAdapter('provider');
    ctrl.ownerRoleAdapter = ReferenceTableDataAdapter('dss_report_owner_contact');
    ctrl.providerIssueStatusAdapter = ReferenceTableDataAdapter('provider_issue_status');
    ctrl.providerIssueSiteAdapter = ReferenceTableDataAdapter('provider_issue_site');
    ctrl.providerIssuePriorityAdapter = ReferenceTableDataAdapter('provider_issue_priority');
    ctrl.providerIssueCategoryAdapter = ReferenceTableDataAdapter('provider_issue_category');

    if($routeParams.issue_code) {
        isExisting = true;
        initPromises.push(IssueService.get({id: $routeParams.issue_code}).$promise.then(function (data) {
            ctrl.issue = data;

            // placing this on the controller for the Parent Issue grid (if exists). Grid needs list of objects...
            ctrl.parentActivities = [{'parent_provider_activity':ctrl.issue.parent_provider_activity,
                                      'parent_provider_activity_activity_date':ctrl.issue.parent_provider_activity_activity_date,
                                      'parent_provider_activity_description': ctrl.issue.parent_provider_activity_description}];
        }));

    } else {
        ctrl.issue = IssueService.wrapData({
            description: '',
            resolution: '',
            status: 'N',
            site: '',
            priority: 'N',
            category: '',
            provider: $routeParams.provider_code,
            issue_date: new Date(),
            owner_role: currentUser
        });

        ctrl.hide_resolution = true;
        //ctrl.issue_date = new Date();

        /* An issue may be created from a provider */
        if($routeParams.provider_code) {
            initPromises.push(ProviderService.get({id: $routeParams.provider_code}).$promise.then(function (data) {
                ctrl.issue.provider = data.provider_code;
            }));
        }
    }

    /* Issues can have their due dates set based on their priority */
    initPromises.push(IssuePriorityService.getPrioritiesMap().then(function (priorities) {
        issuePriority = priorities;
        if(!isExisting) {
            ctrl.issue.due_date = moment(DateService.todayAsUtcDate()).add(issuePriority.N, 'day').toDate();
        }
    }));

    /* Initialization */
    $q.all(initPromises).then(function () {
        /* Allow editing existing record only by owner & admins */
        if(!isExisting || ctrl.isAdmin || ctrl.issue.owner_role === cpm.authentication.user.report_ownership_role_code) {
            ctrl.readOnly = false;
        }

        // TODO: when grid actions are added
        // ctrl.activitiesGrid.hideAddButton = ctrl.readOnly;

        DirtyFormCheckingService($scope, 'issueForm', ctrl.issue);
    });

    ctrl.setDueDate = function (newModel, newCode) {
        ctrl.issue.due_date = moment(ctrl.issue.issue_date).add(issuePriority[newCode], 'day').toDate();
    };

    ctrl.setResolutionDate = function (newModel, newCode) {
        // ctrl.hide_resolution = (newCode !== 'R');
        if (newCode == 'R') {
            ctrl.issue.resolution_date = DateService.todayAsUtcDate();
        } else {
            ctrl.issue.resolution_date = null;
        }
    };

    $scope.$watch('ctrl.issue.status', function (newCode) {
        if(ctrl.issue) {
            ctrl.hide_resolution = (newCode !== 'R');
        }
    });

    ctrl.setStatus = function (event){
        if (ctrl.issue.resolution_date) {
            ctrl.issue.status = "R";
        } else {
            ctrl.issue.status = "N";
        }
    };

    ctrl.submitSuccess = function() {
        $location.url('/');
    };

    ctrl.parentActivityConfig = {
        modelSetName: 'parentIssues',
        actions: {
            editRow: {
                label: function(row) {
                    return ctrl.readOnly ? 'View' : 'Edit';
                },
                active: true,
                callback: function(row){
                    $location.path('/activity/'+ctrl.issue.parent_provider_activity);
                }
            },
            deleteRow: {
                active: false
            }
        },
        rowActions: ['editRow'],
        columns: [
            {col_description: 'Activity Date',
             datatype: 'date',
             model_field: 'parent_provider_activity_activity_date',
             field_type: 'american_date',
             field_name: 'activityDate'
            },
            {col_description: 'Description',
             datatype: 'text',
             model_field: 'parent_provider_activity_description',
             field_type: 'text',
             field_name: 'description'
            },
        ]
    };


    ctrl.activitiesTableConfig = {
        modelSetName: "activities",
        serializerChildName: 'activities',
        actions: {
            addRow: {
                label: 'Add Activity',
                callback: function(){
                    $location.path('/provider/'+ctrl.issue.provider+'/add_activity/'+ctrl.issue.provider_issue_code);
                },
                active: function(row) {return !ctrl.readOnly;}
            },
            editRow: {
                label: function(row) {
                    return getNameForEdit(row.modelSet);
                },
                active: true,
                callback: function(row){
                    $location.path('/activity/'+row.modelSet.provider_activity_code);
                }
            },
            deleteRow: {
                active: function(row) {return !ctrl.readOnly;},
                callback: function(row){
                    _.pull(ctrl.issue.activities, row.modelSet);
                }
            }
        },
        rowActions: ['editRow', 'deleteRow'],
        columns: [
            {col_description: 'Date',
             datatype: 'date',
             model_field: 'activity_date',
             field_type: 'american-date',
             field_name: 'activity_date'
         },
            {col_description: 'Type',
             datatype: 'text',
             model_field: 'provider_activity_type_description',
             field_type: 'text',
             field_name: 'provider_activity_type_description'
         },
            {col_description: 'Notes',
             datatype: 'text',
             model_field: 'description',
             field_type: 'text',
             field_name: 'description'
         },
            {col_description: 'Owner',
             datatype: 'text',
             model_field: 'owner_comp_name',
             field_type: 'text',
             field_name: 'owner_comp_name'
         },
        ]
    };
}]);
```

Comment: sorry to tell you but i dont like the code i see here: you have angular directives and among them you trying to force data into html with some vanilla (pure) javascript. If angular already involved - why not to use it?

Comment: That is the issue I am facing. using angular I am not able to get the current date on the html. I have added javascript code in html only for test purpose, i.e. to get the current date and check if I can pass it to function. Please let me know if you have the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying my best to understand your question, but there's a lot of code to look through here. I do understand that you're trying to pass the current date to a function named "same-or-earlier than." However I can't seem to find a function with that name in your controller file.

I'm assuming that you've got a custom directive (attribute directive) that accepts the current date.

Either way, a simple solution for your problem of passing the current date could be to write a small function that when invoked returns the date using Javascript's native "Date" object.

Perhaps like this in your controller:

```
ctrl.returnCurDate = function() {
  return new Date();
};
```

That way in your markup, you can invoke the method we've defined since it's attached to the scope of your controller.

```
same-or-earlier-than = "ctrl.returnCurDate()"
```

I hope I'm answering your problem in a relevant fashion, please feel free to ask further if I've misunderstood your question.

Best of luck.

P.S. Inherently there are some pain-in-the-butt formatting issues that come with using JS's native Date constructor, I would consider using a library such as "Moment.js" to relieve you of parsing the returned value when invoking:

```
new Date();
```

Comment: Thanks, your understanding is right. but problem is I am not able to pass it to the required class inside the **hh-model-form**  tag it becomes blank or no value. but I am able to print the date outside the tag as updated in above html.   I have pasted my full html code.